# using Python for-loop to extract information from multiple API calls but getting info 5x+ copied

Tags: python, json, api, for-loop, if-statement

I'm iterating through a dictionary with travel locations and start/end dates. I'm requesting weather info for those dates from an API and getting (at least for the most part) a list of JSON responses. I then iterate through the list of JSON response using conditionals (if/elif) to pull out the information I want to keep and append the info to empty lists. When I print the lists later, the values are repeated up to 5x or more (way too many times for the query parameters I input).

```
baseURL = "https://api.globe.gov/search/v1/measurement/protocol/measureddate/point/distance/?protocols=air_temp_dailies&protocols=humidity_noons&protocols=precipitations&protocols=sky_conditions"

## iterrate through weather_params dict to pull out query parameters
## range(1,4) is because there are 3 cities in the dict and the keys are integers (need to start at 1)
for j in range(1,4):
    travel_start = weather_params["travel_details"][j]["traveldates_start"]
    travel_end = weather_params["travel_details"][j]["traveldates_end"]  
    start_date = f"2018-{travel_start}"
    end_date = f"2018-{travel_end}"
    city = weather_params["travel_details"][j]["city"]
    location = gn.geocode(city) 
    time.sleep(5)
    lat = location.latitude
    lon = location.longitude
## insert parameters into API query 
    query = f"{baseURL}&startdate={start_date}&enddate={end_date}&lat={lat}&lon={lon}&distanceinkm=100&geojson=FALSE&sample=FALSE"
## run API query for each city at a time
    response = requests.get(f'{query}').json()
## save query response into variable to extract weather info
    JSON_ = response["results"]   ##LIST of dicts
    #     print(JSON_)
## iterate through JSON_ list for each item[i], which are dicts
    for i in range(len(JSON_)):
## create conditional to pull data from response (JSON_ list) for city[i]    
        if JSON_[i]['protocol'] == 'air_temp_dailies':
                    ### Append JSON response values to lists for each output variable
            date.append(JSON_[i]['measuredDate'])
            max_temp.append(JSON_[i]['data']['airtempdailiesMaximumTemp'])
            min_temp.append(JSON_[i]['data']['airtempdailiesMinimumTemp'])
            latitude.append(JSON_[i]['latitude'])
            longitude.append(JSON_[i]['longitude'])
            i = i + 1
        elif JSON_[i]['protocol'] == 'humidity_noons':
            humidity.append(JSON_[i]['data']['humiditynoonsRelativeHumidityPercent'])
            i = i + 1
        elif JSON_[i]['protocol'] == 'precipitations':
            precip.append(JSON_[i]['data']['precipitationsOccurrenceType'])
            i = i + 1
        else: 
            date.append(np.nan)
            max_temp.append(np.nan)
            min_temp.append(np.nan)            
            latitude.append(np.nan)
            longitude.append(np.nan)
            humidity.append(np.nan)            
            precip.append(np.nan)
            i = i + 1
    print(city, travel_start, travel_end, lat, lon, query)
    del JSON_
    j = j + 1
```

Tried:
I originally had saved the JSON responses from the query into a list and then iterated through that list in another cell to extract the info but it got too complicated to iterate through so many lists (e.i., list of list of dicts) so I figured if I moved the for-loop extracting the info from the response into the actual query loop I could kill two birds with one loop giant loop.

I’ve also tried removing the different for-loops, but it usually only extracts the first city’s data and not the rest. so either I have two for-loops at 45 data entries, or I have one for-loop with 4 data entries. I need something in between, around 13 data entries give or take.

when I:
`print(len(date),len(max_temp),len(min_temp),len(precip),len(humidity))
print(f"date{date}")`

output:
45 45 45 45 52
date['2018-03-03', '2018-03-04', '2018-03-05', '2018-03-06', nan, nan, nan, '2018-03-12', '2018-03-13', '2018-03-14', '2018-03-15', nan, nan, nan, nan, '2018-03-12', '2018-03-13', '2018-03-14', '2018-03-15', '2018-03-12', '2018-03-13', '2018-03-14', '2018-03-15', nan, '2018-03-12', '2018-03-13', '2018-03-14', '2018-03-15', '2018-03-12', '2018-03-13', '2018-03-14', '2018-03-15', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]

Comment: Have you done any debugging? As an aside, why are you incrementing `i` and `j`?

Comment: Incrementing i and j to make sure the "counter" goes up (so that the index value of the list can be reached). Honestly, it worked without the incrementation. It was an attempt at trying everything I could think of to make it work.

Comment: There's no need to increment them, that's the point of using `for _ in range():`.